# How do I pass a method as parameter to an Angular component to work with "change" or "click" of an input inside the component?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using Angular version 9.1.11 to build a platform, so I made an angular component for a select box, passing the options of the select box as an array of objects [{value: string, name: string, selected?: boolean}] and some other options.

But I am stuck at this: I need, in this case, to change the value of one select depending on other select's selected option, so I need to pass a method at the parents component and only trigger it when the select changes, getting the value of itself.

As an example, if I have two selects, one with continents and another with countries and when I select the continent, it gives me the countries of that continent on the other.

For reasons of styling and validation, my component uses an `<input>`.
Here is the template of the component:

select.component.html

```
<div class="form-group ef__select-wrapper" (click)="clickWrapper()">
    <label [attr.for]="id" [class.disabled]="disabled">{{ label }}</label>
    <div class="ef__select">
        <div class="ef__select__trigger">
            <input required readonly type="text" 
                *ngIf="opcaoSelecionada" 
                class="ef__form-control ef__text-corpo-p ef__select-input" 
                [attr.data-value]="selectedOption.value" 
                [placeholder]="selectInput">
            <div class="arrow"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="ef__options">
            <span #efOption
                *ngFor="let option of options" 
                class="ef__option ef__text-corpo-p" (click)="clickOption($event)" 
                [class.selected]="option.selected" 
                [class.disabled]="option.disabled" 
                [attr.data-value]="option.value">{{ option.name }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

select.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { SelectOption } from 'src/app/_models/SelectOption';

@Component({
  selector: 'ef-select',
  templateUrl: './select.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./select.component.scss']
})
export class SelectComponent implements OnInit {

  disabled;
  selectInput: string;
  selectedOption: SelectOption = { name: "Selecione uma opção", value: 0 };

  @Input() options: SelectOption[]; //array com as opcoes do select
  @Input() id: string;
  @Input() label: string;

  constructor(private elem: ElementRef) {
    this.selectedOption = { name: "Selecione uma opção", value: 0 };
    this.selectInput = this.selectedOption.name;
    window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      let target = <HTMLElement>e.target; 
      const select = elem.nativeElement.querySelector('.ef__select');
      if (!select.contains(e.target) && !target.classList.contains('disabled')) {
          select.classList.remove('open');
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.options.length; i++) {
      if(this.options[i].selected){
        this.selectedOption = this.options[i];
        this.selectInput = this.options[i].name;
      }
    }
  }

  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void{
    this.disabled = isDisabled;
  }

  clickWrapper() {
    this.elem.nativeElement.querySelector('.ef__select').classList.toggle('open');
  }

  clickOption(elem2) {
    let dom_option = elem2.target;
    let dom_options = dom_option.parentNode;

    if(!dom_option.classList.contains('selected') && !dom_option.classList.contains('disabled')){
      if(dom_options.querySelector('.ef__option.selected')) {
        dom_options.querySelector('.ef__option.selected').classList.remove('selected');
      }
      dom_option.closest('.ef__select').querySelector('.ef__select__trigger .ef__select-input').value = dom_option.textContent;
      dom_option.classList.add('selected');
      dom_options.parentNode.querySelector('.ef__select-input').classList.add('ef__valid-form-control');

      this.selectedOption.value = dom_option.dataset.value;
    }
  }
}
```

To call the component:

```
<ef-select
   label='Continent'
   id='continent'
   name="continent"
   [options]="continents">
</ef-select>
```

Where continents = [{value: 0, name: "Africa"}, {value: 1, name: America}, ...]

Comment: Whats the point of passing a function here? You must have a parent component with multiple select, so that means the parent is getting the data and passing it to the children. Just have an output from the children saying: I changed with the selected option as a parameter and then change the value of the input of the second component

Comment: Just a side comment, doing all that Dom manipulation is not angular best practice.

Comment: ukn, sorry if I'm trying to complicate things, I'm new with Angular. Are you talking about an @Output? I' not sure if I understand

Comment: @wlf has a point.

Comment: wlf, yea... I read about it.. I am used to working with jquery and stuff.. So i do a lot of DOM manipulation. I tried to figure out a way to achieve the same results without dom manipulation, but couldn't do it.. Do you have any documentation or any sugestions? Thank you for your comment

Comment: Yes Im talking about an @Output. If you want to manipulate the dom, you should use the renderer2

Comment: Ok, thank you! I will do it that way and update my answer

Comment: Given the OP is a new angular user I suggest he steers clear of Renderer2 for now, if at all possible.

Comment: João, re Dom manipulation - sorry to be harsh but I would suggest starting from scratch and following a suitable tutorial such as https://netbasal.com/create-a-custom-select-component-in-angular-complete-with-virtual-scrolling-c29e24f72006